# GDM does not display session, or top row icons

Tags: 14.04, gdm, icon-themes

I switched recently to the Gnome desktop environment. I was running Xubuntu, but got fed up with the bugs so decided to install Gnome-Shell.

All was fine until I removed Xubunt and Xfce in an attempt to resolve a SUSPEND issue.

Now the session list button (the Gear ICON) and top row icons are no longer showing. If I click on the place where they are meant to be the menus show.

Missing gear icon: [IMAGE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yt9s7206kfw2y39/2015-06-08%2013.18.38.jpg?dl=0)

It seems to have lost its icon theme. I have installed [GDM3SETUP](https://github.com/Nano77/gdm3setup) which allows me to alter theming of the GDM, however the icons do not register.

Is there a way to reset the GDM? I have tried purging and manually removing all GDM files I could find, then reinstalling, but the same issue.... I suspect that a setting somewhere is being remembered and not being cleared.

Any ideas where the conf file is for the GDM?

Gnome 3.10 (Ubuntu 14.04)

GDM Version 3.10.0.1-Oubuntu3.1

Thanks

EDIT:

Tried updating cache

```
sudo /usr/bin/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders --update-cache
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the issue is that some icon themes are not being applied correctly.

What I did to resolve my issue.

1. Reinstalled using synaptic all files relating to: gnome-shell* gnome-session* gnome-icon* gnome-desktop gnome3
2. Using [GDM3SETUP](https://github.com/Nano77/gdm3setup) applied a theme

Not sure why there is an issue here, probably has something to with the initial installation which was Xubuntu.